# Why flowlayoutpanel controls count 0 C#

Tags: c#, events, count, controls, flowlayoutpanel

I'm creating 3 textbox and add to the flowlayoutpanel, but flowlayoutpanel control count 0.Why does the number of checks appear to be 0, what is the reason?

```
  internal void Create_TextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var Dynamic = sender as TextBox;
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+");
        Match match = regex.Match(Dynamic.Name);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            if(Dynamic.Name == "txtCash"+match.Value)
            {
                TextBox DynamicDataOne = fp.Controls.Find("txt" + match.Value, true)[0] as TextBox;
                TextBox DynamicDataTwo = fp.Controls.Find("txtTwo" + match.Value, true)[0] as TextBox;
                int _One;
                int _Two;
                if (int.TryParse(DynamicDataOne.Text, out _One) && int.TryParse(DynamicDataTwo.Text, out _Two))
                    Dynamic.Text = (_One * _Two).ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can easily do this like:

```
var textboxes = fp.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Where(x=> Regex.IsMatch(x.Name, "txtCash\\d+"));
```

Comment: The problem is:  TextBox DynamicDataOne = fp.Controls.Find("txt" + match.Value, true)[0] as TextBox; Exception : Index out of range exception

Comment: Flowlayoutpanel, comes to control count : 0

Comment: Yes, but it gives an error ; 
CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection' to 'bool'
CS1662 Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type

Comment: @MustafaGürses Aman tanrım, I had done a mistake. it should be `IsMatch`, instead of `Matches`. I had corrected my answer please check the edited answer.

Comment: I tried and it works. But how can I access the textbox.text content with this code?

Comment: I don't know much about LINQ :(

Comment: well now `foreach(TextBox tb in textboxes) MessageBox.Show(tb.Text);`

Comment: I've tested it, but it doesn't rotate in foreach. :(

Comment: it should may be you don't have as many textboxes that matches the condition as you think.

Comment: I'm dynamically adding text boxes
And I add numbers to their names they do not mix

Comment: My problem is that the number of checks in flowlayoutpanel is 0.
But the controls are added

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way;

```
    string GetTextBox()
    {
        TextBox txt = fp.Controls.Find("txt1", true)[0] as TextBox;
        return txt.Text;
    }
```

But why can't I do it in the event?

Comment: Dont answer your own Question or edit your Question with modified answer.